# Python 3 multiprocessing: internal and timeout error handling and callbacks

Tags: python, python-3.x, callback, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to use Pool.starmap_async to run some code that takes multiple parameters as inputs, in order to quickly sweep through a parameter space. The code runs a linalg function that sometimes does not converge, and instead throws a np.linalg.LinAlgError. In this case I'd like my code to return np.nan, and carry on its merry way. I would also, ideally, like to specify a timeout so that the code gives up after a set number of seconds and continues on to a different parameter combination.

`# This is actually some long function that sometimes returns a linalg error
def run_solver(A, B):
    return A+B`

`if __name__ == '__main__':`

```
# Parameters    
Asearch = np.arange(4, 8, 1)
Bsearch = np.arange(0.2, 2, 0.2)

# Search all combinations of Qsearch and Rmsearch 
AB = np.array(list(itertools.product(Qsearch, Rmsearch)))
A = AB[:, 0]
B = AB[:, 1]

result = {}

with Pool(processes=15) as pool:

    def cb(r):
        print("callback")
        result[params] = r

    def ec(r):
        result[params] = np.nan
        print("error callback")
        raise np.linalg.LinAlgError

    try:
        params = (zip(A, B))
        r = pool.starmap_async(run_solver, params, callback=cb, error_callback=ec)
        print(r.get(timeout=10))

    except np.linalg.LinAlgError:
        print("parameters did not converge")

    except mp.context.TimeoutError:
        print("Timeout error. Continuing...")

pickle.dump(result, open("result.p", "wb"))
print("pickling output:", result)`
```

I have tried to catch the TimeoutError as an exception so that the code will continue, and I'm purposefully raising the LinAlgError because I'm trying to pick apart when the code runs out of time vs fails to converge in time -- I realize that's redundant. For one thing, the result dictionary does not end up being how I intended: is there a way to query the current process's parameters and use those as the dictionary keys? Also, if a Timeout error occurs I would ideally flag those parameters in some way -- what's the best way to do this?

Finally, why in this code is callback only called once? Shouldn't it be called as each process successfully completes? The code returns a dictionary where all of the parameters are crammed into a single key (as a .zip file) and all of the answers are a list in the key value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think I'm fully understanding the problem here, but what if you simplified it down to something like this, where you catch the `LinAlgError` in the calculation function.

Here `apply_async` is used to get a result object for each task sent to the pool.  This allows you to easily apply a timeout to the result objects.

```
def run_solver(A, B):
    try:
       result = A + B
    except np.linalg.LinAlgError:
       result = np.nan
    return result

results = []
with Pool(processes=15) as pool:
    params = (zip(A, B))
    result_pool = [pool.apply_async(run_solver, args) for args in params]
    for result in result_pool:
        try:
            results.append(result.get(15))
        except context.TimeoutError:
            # do desired action on timeout
            results.append(None)
```

Comment: I like the idea, but this code doesn't work -- the map object isn't iterable. Your verbatim code returns `for result in pool.starmap_async(run_solver, params):
TypeError: 'MapResult' object is not iterable`

Comment: I've updated it with a different method to achieve something similar to what I was thinking.